# How to create long press menu like pinterest? [React Native]

Tags: react-native, menu, pinterest, long-press

I'm trying to create a menu like pinterest, if you long press the item the menu appear and by moving your finger you can select the option you want.
How can I create something like that in react native?

[image]

Comment: Have you managed to do that @PaulRock ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Pressable ( react native )](https://reactnative.dev/docs/pressable)  or [TouchableOpacity( react native )](https://reactnative.dev/docs/touchableopacity)  to use a long press action and after action you can create other button for your menu

Other suggestion here try open link [Demo Expo](https://snack.expo.io/@sodik82/react-native-popup-menu-with-trigger-long-press)